# printing int array as string

Tags: c, string, printf

I am trying to print int array with %s. But it is not working. Any ideas why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
    int a[8];

    a[0]='a';
    a[1]='r';
    a[2]='i';
    a[3]='g';
    a[4]='a';
    a[5]='t';
    a[6]='o';
    a[7] = '\0';

    printf("%s", a);
}
```

It prints just a.
I tried with short as well, but it also does not work.

Comment: What happens if you change `int a[8]` to `char a[8]`? Whats different about the two? How do you think that difference affects how `printf()` formats and emits a string to stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to print a int array, where each element has a size of 4 byte (4 chars, on 32bit machines at least). `printf()` interprets it as char array so the first element looks like: 
`'a' \0 \0 \0` 
to `printf()`. As `printf()` stops at the first `\0` it finds, it only prints the 'a'.

Use a char array instead.

Comment: On some platforms `'a'` as an int may be represented like `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x41`.  So you won't even get `a`!  The first byte will be zero.

Comment: I think he's a beginner so I don't wanted to confuse him with endianess, but you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the way integers are represented - use a debugger if you must. Looking at the memory you will see plenty of 0 bytes, and `%s` stops when it reaches a 0 byte.

> It prints just a.

That's why it prints just `a`. Afterwards it encounters a 0 byte and it stops.

Comment: okay thanks :). Is there any other way to print int as string. I mean just with printf, without using loops or int to char conversions? For some reasons (beyond my scope) string is in int and not in char.

Comment: @sakura If `int` happens to be of the same length as `wchar_t`, then you may have some success printing it using `wprintf()`. Else no, there's no other option than looping over the string.

Answer (score 1):

Because you declared a as an integer, so those signle characters you initialized would result in an error. You must change it to a char variable. However to save time, just make the variable a pointer using the asterisk character, which then allows you to make a single string using double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`int a[8]` means array of **8 ints** or `8*(4 bytes)`  - Say **32** bit architecture

`a[0] = 'a'` stores in the first int index as `'a''\0''\0''\0'`
`a[1] = 'r'`  as `'r''\0''\0''\0'`   and so on . . .

`%s` represents any **C-style string** ie. any `string` followed by a `'\0'` character

So

```
 printf("%s", a);
```

searches for trailing `'\0'` character and just prints "a" assuming it is the entire `string`